# 16.04 - Bluetooth error "Not enough free handles to register service"

Tags: bluetooth

does anyone know how to get bluetooth working? I've read much about this specific bug, someone says that it has been fixed in 16.04, but I am still affected (Dell XPS 15 9550, Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install)

```
~$ uname -r
4.4.0-22-generic

~$ sudo service bluetooth status -l
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mar 2016-05-17 12:39:44 CEST; 12min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 3459 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─3459 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Not enough free handles to register service
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Not enough free handles to register service
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Current Time Service could not be registered
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Not enough free handles to register service
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Not enough free handles to register service
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Sap driver initialization failed.
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
mag 17 12:39:44 xxx bluetoothd[3459]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

I tried almost everything I found on Google but it still does not detect any device (mouse, keyboard, phone, nothing).

Thank you.

Comment: It remains unfixed on Ubuntu 16.04 as of Sep 2016:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1490349

Comment: Still open: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1490349